# add one month in excel into the current month

Tags: excel

In cell A1 I have the date `09/21/2010`. In cell A2 I have `=MONTH(A1)`, to display the month in cell A1, which is 9 for September. In cell A3, I would like Excel to display the month after September, which is 10 for October. I tried `=MONTH(A1)+1` but that does't work. Can anyone please tell me how to do it? Thank you for your help.

Comment: So if I enter =MONTH(A1), I get the month as 9, which is fine. But if I do =MONTH(A1)+1, I get 1/10/1990.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use the EDATE function: `=EDATE(A1, 1)` then format the row
or use DATE such as: `=DATE(YEAR(A1), MONTH(A1)+1, DAY(A1))`

Comment: yeah, I assumed I'd hear "it returns 9/99/1990", I get this question so often from students I've tutored that I just start with using a full date function to avoid it (also the next question will be "how can I change the day and year too")